# String::scan with string argument behave strange

Tags: ruby, regex, string

According to [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-scan), `#scan` should accept both `String` and `Regexp` instances as parameter. But tests show strange behaviour:

```
▶ cat scantest.rb 
#!/usr/bin/ruby
puts '='*10
puts 'foo'.scan '.'
puts '='*10
puts 'foo'.scan /./
puts '='*10

▶ rb scantest.rb
# ⇒ ==========
# ⇒ ==========
# ⇒ f
# ⇒ o
# ⇒ o
# ⇒ ==========
```

Inside both `pry` and `irb`, it doesn't properly scan for a string as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The behaviour is correct. What did confuse you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With string `'.'`, it scans for literal dots:

```
'foo'.scan '.'
# => []
'fo.o'.scan '.'
# => ["."]
```

While with regular expression `/./`, it matches any characters (except newline):

```
'foo'.scan /./
# => ["f", "o", "o"]
"foo\nbar".scan /./
# => ["f", "o", "o", "b", "a", "r"]
```

Comment: Ahh. I'm too slow today. :)

Comment: Arrgh. Thanks, it was evident.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, You are not slow. Your comment was written before mine. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev to say the truth, it’s _me_ here who is too slow today :-)

Answer (score 0):

your `scan` should have a `parameter` that match the string you want to `scan` otherwise it will return empty arrray

My case:

```
irb(main):039:0> "foo".scan("o")
=> ["o", "o"]
```

Your case

```
   'foo'.scan '.'
    # => []
```

There is no dot`.` present on the `'foo'` string so `scan` return `empty array`